# Pythonic multiple inheritance to generate collections of custom classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, mixins, method-resolution-order

I've got two class trees in my Python code:

```
       BaseComponent                      BaseSeries
      /      |      \                          |
Resistor Capacitor Inductor                 ESeries
```

The `BaseSeries` class tree implements preferred numbers such as the [E-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-series_of_preferred_numbers), and generates sets of values between a pair of powers (e.g. `[1.0, 2.2, 4.7, 10, 22, 47, 100, 220, 470]` for the E3 series with exponents between 1 to 3).

By default, `ESeries` and any other instance of `BaseSeries` creates sequences of `float` objects. I'd like to use these classes to instead create sequences of `Resistor`, `Capacitor` and `Inductor` objects. Ideally, the individual `Resistor`, `Capacitor`, `Inductor` and `ESeries` classes would remain usable on their own (i.e. not rely on methods being implemented by other classes).

This sounds like a job for multiple inheritance, but I'm a bit confused about how best to implement this in Python (3). Ideally I'd like to just define something like:

```
class ResistorESeries(Resistor, ESeries):
    pass

class CapacitorESeries(Capacitor, ESeries):
    pass

class InductorESeries(Inductor, ESeries):
    pass
```

in order to create classes that yield sequences of resistors, capacitors and inductors, **but I don't know how best to tell `BaseSeries` instances to create objects of type `Resistor`, `Capacitor` and `Inductor`**. I can think of two ways, but I can't decide which one is best, and I have a feeling there is a simpler, more Pythonic way that I'm missing:

1. have `BaseSeries` contain a property or variable pointing to the element type (e.g. `Resistor`) set either by the constructor, a class variable in the child class (e.g. `Resistor.ELEMENT_TYPE = Resistor`) or with an abstract property provided by the child class:

   ```
   class BaseSeries(object):
       ...
       def elements(self):
           # loop over numbers in this series
           for v in self.values():
               yield self.element_type(v)

       @property
       @abc.abstractmethod
       def element_type(self):
           return NotImplemented

   class ESeries(BaseSeries):
       ....

   class BaseComponent(object):
       ...
       @property
       def element_type(self):
           return self

   class Resistor(BaseComponent):
       ...

   class ResistorESeries(Resistor, ESeries):
       # now BaseSeries' `element_type` property is provided by `BaseComponent`
       pass
   ```

   This would mean `ESeries` cannot be used on its own as a concrete object, as it does not implement this property/variable, which is not ideal.
2. use `self` when creating elements in `BaseSeries`, where `self` will, as long as `Resistor` is earlier in the method resolution order, refer to the desired element:

   ```
   class BaseSeries(object):
       ...
       def elements(self):
           # loop over numbers in this series
           for v in self.values():
               # self here would refer to `Resistor` in
               # `ResistorESeries` instances
               yield self(v)

   class ESeries(BaseSeries):
       ....

   class BaseComponent(object):
       ...

   class Resistor(BaseComponent):
       ...

   class ResistorESeries(Resistor, ESeries):
       pass
   ```

This has the downside that, in instances of `ESeries` without being used as a mix-in, `self` will refer to itself, which does not support the correct `__init__` signature.

So, does anyone have an idea of how best to do this in a Pythonic way, with maximum ability to reuse classes on their own?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely mixing some concepts there - notably "instances" and "classes" - your example calls that do `self(v)` are perplexing.

I can't see from your design why the classes on the BaseComponent tree would need to be inherited along the BaseSeries tree: can't the component type simply be an attribute on the BaseSeries class?

It is simply a matter of using a class attribute, and in the code suggested on your first attempt, use a prosaic `if` statement.

```
class BaseSeries:
   component = None

    def elements(self):
        # loop over numbers in this series
        for v in self.values():
            yield self.component(v) if self.component else v

class Capacitor(BaseComponent):
   ...


class CapacitorSeries(BaseSeries):
   component = Capacitor
```

If you think you need multiple inheritance, you can just go for your idea of using a property, and use the same "if" statement there. But if both hierarchies are that ortogonal, I don't see why force the use of multiple inheritance, just because the language permits it.

Maybe you prefer to have it the other way around: a factory method on the component tree that will take an ESeries class as input, and extract the values from that ...

Anyway, you are not making clear the disctinction of classes and instances there. Do you need to have a way to produce several subclasses of
"CapacitorESeries", each *class*  for a different value?
Or would you need just instances of "Capacitors", each for a different value produced on the series?

```
class BaseComponent:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def series_factory(self, series):
          for value in series.values():
                yield self.__class__(value)
```

Of course, there could be use cases for really needing classes for everything you claim, including the factories for series of classes, but your use of `self` as a callable in your snippets suggests that your stance on that is not that solid.

In that case, first, you need all methods to make proper use of `super`. even if they ar enot supposed to exist across both hierarchies, using `super` will just call the proper method on the superclasses. But for methods like `__init__` this is just needed.

If you design a proper `__init__` method using `super`, and always using named parameters, your second strategy will work out of the box, just fixing the instantiating call  (to something other than `self(v)`. Using named parameters and passing the remaining parameters to `super` will ensure each class in the tree consumes what it needs of those parameters - and when Python gets to the root of both your hierarchies and calls `object`'s `__init__`, no parameter is remaining,

```
class BaseSeries:
    def __init__(self, value_min, value_max, **kwargs):
         self.value_min = value_min
         selfvalue_max = value_max
         super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def elements(self):
        # loop over numbers in this series
        for v in self.values():
            yield self.__class__(value_min = self.value_min, value_max=self.value_max, value=value)

class BaseComponent:
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
         self.value = value

...

class CapacitorESeries(Capacitor, Eseries):
    pass
```